# A strange sql bug (multipart identifier) about sql server

Tags: sql-server

I encounter a strange bug - multpart identifier "tableabc..fielda" cannot be bound today.

In the above sql, I accidentally add one more dot in the query.

I key in 2 dots in the sql query.
It works in the development server (mssql 2005).
When it comes to staging server (also mssql 2005), the above error occurs.

What's the cause of that?
Both databases are mssql 2005. However, one works fine and another one fails.
Why?

Comment: This is most likely happening because table..column is invalid but database..table is valid.

If you could post a query sample that would make it possible to see the potential cause of your problem.

Comment: But the same query is run on mssql 2005, maybe the mssql2005 in our development server is more updated.

Comment: @Billy - post the query - then we can choose the best course of action to determine why you are getting this error.  Without the query we are working blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you use 2 dots to denote the default schema, i.e. database.schema.table as database..table

You seem to be suggesting that tableabc is a table, and fielda is a column, so you wouldn't have a level between them?

can you confirm what these objectnames are suppose to be?

Do these/this object exist on the staging server?

What is the default schema of the user you are connected as?

Comment: "2 dots" denotes the default schema? Any document talks about this? Thanks.

Comment: as in 'select * from database..table' - the implied schema will be the one that is the default for the user that is connected.  It might be better if you post the query you are trying to run, with this fragment in context.